# Why is then is not a function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-props

this.props.promise.then is not a function error. Why?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        data: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.promise.then(
        value => this.setState({loading: false, data: value}),
        error => this.setState({loading: false, error: error}));
}
```

component call:

```
<Child promise={this.state.data} />
```

this.state.data is an array

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check what `typeof(this.props.promise)` is, and what it contains. Looks like bad data being passed to the constructor?

Comment: Why do you expect an array to behave like a promise? Is it an array of promises? If so, use `Promise.all`

Comment: Typeof returns an object.

Comment: The array passed is being constructed asynchronously from an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this.props.promise.then is not a function error. Why?

Because whatever it is that you're passing down to your component named as `promise` does not actually hold a promise.

And since you mentioned that `typeof this.props.promise` returns an `object`, you can visualise your code as essentially doing this:

`someObjectNamedPromise.then( ... )`

And since `someObjectNamedPromise` doesn't have a property named `then` that's pointing to a function, you get an error that's telling you exactly that.

Comment: Thanks Linas! You were right about the props not being a promise. I saved the URL from an API call into the parent component's state and then passed that as a props. To make the props a promise, I just made the props equal to the API URL call. Now it works like a charm!